# Simulink and SIL error due to unsupported continuous sample time

Tags: matlab, code-generation, simulink

I have a 3 simulink models: the first is used as multiple-instance component inside the second; the second is a component inside the third (the third one is just used for testing purpuse and inkect test stimuli on the second).

If I simulate my model in "Normal" way all works fine.
If I set my HW configuration (ARM Cortex) and try to run it in "SIL" mode it doesn't work because "The component has an unsupported continuous sample time. Input and output ports with continuous sample times are not supported. To avoid this error you should update the component so that there are no continuous sample times crossing its boundary."

Same error also trying to simulate the first model (the inner one).

Do you have an idea to solve my problem?

Thank you.

Comment: Could you include a picture of the diagram that is producing the problem?

Comment: Clicking "start simulation" from inner model (the first one in my description) I already get this error. Its picture is enough? It just have one input, one output and a stateflow model in the middle. In stateflow there are two variables: one for input and one for output and their type is "inherit".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Use discrete sample times, not continuous ones. You can display the sample times in your model to see which ones are continuous and you need to change, see the [documentation](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/simulink/ug/how-to-view-sample-time-information.html) for more details.

Comment: Thank you, the link you privided me is nice, and following a link from thata page I found another one insteresting too: www.mathworks.it/it/help/simulink/ug/how-to-specify-the-sample-time.html  Now, declaring a sample time to every signal input type-converter (in my model there was one of them for each signal), my signals become digital. But  I not understand why just 1 signal not change and remains analog. It is marked as digital, but enter in a model in wich its input-signal name is marked as analog. Inside that model it enter in a hybrid model (in wich every variable as set as inherit).

Comment: You probably need to do the same inside the referenced model the signal enters.

Comment: Yes... but I'm afraid that in this way, I may introduce some delay. I have to give a try...